# Get order details in Woocommerce email templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'm trying to customize my Woocommerce Emails and I created already a html template for it, which already works.

The Problem that I have is that it's not displaying the woocommerce variable like for example:

- this way `{order_number}`
- or this way `{order_shipping_address}`

I always have to put them like this:

```
<?php echo $order->billing_last_name; ?>
```

Below is a snippet how the HTML Code looks like:

```
<span data-key="1468270_order_number">Bestellnr.:</span> #<?php echo $order->id; ?>
```

So it's plain html file with this php variable at the places where I need them. I put the html file into **Woocommerce > Settings > E-Mails > New Order**

Do I have to wrap it all into a php file or how do I get variables like `{order_number}` working.  On this [related Woocommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/email-variables-and-merge-tags/) there are a lot of Variables without, but I can't make them work.

How can I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder `{order_number}` (or some other ones) are only used in emails subject settings. Have a look to *"[Get custom email placeholder value on Woocommerce custom email content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438921/get-custom-email-placeholder-value-on-woocommerce-custom-email-content/53439063#53439063)"* related answer thread…

So **it's not a variable** but a **placeholder** and can not be used on Woocommerce email templates *(or available hooks)*.

Also your question code is outdated since Woocommerce 3 as object properties are protected and not anymore accessible directly… You need to use available methods instead (see [CRUD Objects](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0)):

- For the **Order ID**, use `$order->get_id()`
- For the **Order Number**, use `$order->get_order_number()`

So in your code:

```
<span data-key="1468270_order_number">Bestellnr.:</span> #<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>
```

But to use those methods, the **`$order`** Object need to be defined in the template (or the hook).

---

**Related threads:**

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)